# Use jQuery fileDownload to download string instead of document from server

Tags: jquery

I just came across the awesome [fileDownload plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) for jQuery and would like to use it to download a string generated on the server side onto the user's computer. I'm using Python Flask, what I'm doing right now is writing a route and returning that string, but the plugin takes me to a new page that displays the string instead of staying on the same page and downloading the string onto the user's computer as it is supposed to. Here is the route:

```
@app.route("/ode")
def odeDownload():
    return "test"
```

And here is my link:

```
<a href="/ode" class="fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience">Test</a>
```

Is it possible to use the plugin in this way (I don't want to create the file just for the user to download it and then go back and delete that file)? If it is possible, how would I specify the name of the file?